# neural network binary classification softmax logsofmax and loss function

Tags: pytorch, binary, classification, softmax, cross-entropy

I am building a binary classification where the class I want to predict is present only <2% of times. I am using pytorch

The last layer could be `logosftmax` or `softmax`.

`self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)` or `self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)`

my questions

1. I should use `softmax` as it will provide outputs that sum up to 1 and I can check performance for various prob thresholds. is that understanding correct?
2. if I use `softmax` then can I use `cross_entropy` loss? [This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) seems to suggest that it is okay to use
3. if i use `logsoftmax` then can I use `cross_entropy` loss? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494819/use-crossentropyloss-with-logsoftmax) seems to suggest that I shouldnt.
4. if I use `softmax` then is there any better option than `cross_entropy` loss?

   ```
       ` cross_entropy = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_wts)`
   ```

Comment: You have a severe class imbalance. Cross entropy loss alone might not work for you. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766155/1714410) for more details and options.

Comment: thanks, could you reply questions 1,2,3,4? thanks

Comment: After [ECCV](https://eccv2022.ecva.net/) deadline. However, for _binary_ classification one usually use a single output with `sigmoid` activation and [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) and not `softmax` and `CrossEntropy` loss.

Comment: I understand. just yes or no would suffice for time being